# MVC Routing - Url not updating to new route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following MVC route:

```
routes.MapRoute("AccountLookupDirect", 
                        "{culture}/account/{originalSellerId}/{accountNumber}",
                        new {culture = "en-gb", controller = "accountlookup", action = "index", originalSellerId = UrlParameter.Optional, accountNumber = UrlParameter.Optional},
                        new {culture = @"[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}"}
                        );
```

I can browse to a url such as `http://{server}/**account**/{seller}/{accountnumber}` and the page loads as expected. The problem is that when links are generated on a page, the url is not updating to the new route. Instead I get `http://{server}/**{controller}**/{seller}/{accountnumber}`.

The links are generated dynamically using Handlebars templating. The template looks like:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" data-template-name="account-link">
<a href="@Url.Action("index", "accountlookup")/{{ OriginalSeller }}/{{AccountNumber}}">{{ AccountNumber }}</a>
</script>
```

I have deployed the same code on two different servers and it works as expected on one, but not the other.

Comment: How are you generating the links on the page?

Comment: Which other routes have you registered and in which order?

Comment: There is only the route described above and the default route. The default route is last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the cause of this issue was because the servers have a different version of the .NET framework installed. The working server has .NET 4.5 whereas the other only has .NET 4.

Unfortunately as we couldn't install 4.5 on one of the boxes we had to implement a very ugly workaround:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" data-template-name="account-link">
<a href="@(Url.Action("index", "accountlookup", new { originalSellerId = "a", accountNumber = "a" }).Replace("/a/a", ""))/{{ OriginalSeller }}/{{AccountNumber}}">{{ AccountNumber }}</a>
</script>
```